# CSS3 target previous element?

Tags: css, css-selectors

With CSS3 is it possible to target a previous element?

So if i had this mark up:

```
<p>Target Me </p>
<p id="second">Second</p>
```

Something like this would make the text 'Target Me' bold:

```
#id -previous {
   font-weight: bold;
}
```

Comment: Its not possible in CSS3 so Gustov's answer is right if you consider the javascript solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One solution is to do it with jQuery. It would look something like

```
$("#second").prev().css('font-weight', 'bold');
```

Comment: I will if needs be but I was hoping for a CSS3 solution. Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1817792/css-previous-sibling-selector possible duplicate... And as the praised guy says, "No, there is no "previous sibling" selector."